# How to handle multiple stores and multiple store admin users

Tags: commerce, users, organic-groups

Is it possible to create a restaurant(multi-store) online delivery system using Drupal commerce and OG? It has multiple stores(restaurants) in different locations which can be manageable by individual restaurant admins. The super-admin also have full control over all restaurants- can create products for each restaurants.

We have up to 40 restaurants and each restaurants have different products(food items). Each restaurant admin need to add/update  own products and own store addresses, delevery time, etc

I have checked with Commerce Marketplace and seems difficult to implement.

Please share your valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a similar project and I am using commerce marketplace. Had faced some issues, but overall it was a smooth journey using marketplace. Also, it is not difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which I use for a multi-restaurant installation, is an alternative version - [commerce marketplace by maciej.zgadzaj](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/maciej.zgadzaj/1950386).

> Module package providing overrides for default Drupal Commerce
>   behaviors allowing to use DC-based stores to create multiple-merchant
>   marketplace (like Etsy, Amazon, etc).

Admin creates all the stores (restaurants). Then each store has its own products i.e. food items. I believe this version fits better with drupal commerce. Make sure each store's products have unique SKU's.

For a guide on use cases and installation, see [Commerce Marketplace: Installation and use cases](http://zgadzaj.com/commerce-marketplace-installation-and-use-cases). Just make sure you pull the latest version from git.

From your answer, I believe you are using [the other version](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace).